# How to integrate Euler Bending Equation in C++?

Tags: numerical-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to Draw shear force diagram and bending moment diagram of beams. In this, I need to integrate second order differential.
So, Anybody can suggest me, which numerical method should I use?

Comment: This question not enough information.

Comment: Why do you need it in C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can use odeint, which is part of the Boost library, here's a long list of examples [odeint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/all_examples.html)